# Canvas: фиксированная ширина текста

Tags: javascript, html5

Как сделать чтобы текст, нарисованный в canvas имел фиксированную длину, неважно одна там буква или 10. Если одна то растягивается до самых краев чтобы занять всю ширину, если много то сжимаются.